# How to write a Unit Test for a class with a private method which contains HttpClient

Tags: c#, xunit

I'm trying to write a unit tests for one of my ASP.NET Core classes using Xunit, but ran into an issue with MySendAsync() private method that I'm using to send an http request.

I need to find a way to mock http response from the MySendAsync() method.

Perhaps anyone ran into the similar a situation before and might be able to advise on how to mock the response of 'MySendAsync' method in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
public class MyPlatform : BasePlatform, IPlatformAction
{
    private readonly string _apiKey;

    public MyPlatform()
    {
        _apiKey = <MyAPI-Key>;
    }

    public async Task<Token> Authorize(LoginDTO login)
    {
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await MySendAsync("POST", "URI/Authenticate", JsonSerializer.Serialize(login));
        string jsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
            AuthResponseDto results = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuthResponseDto>(jsonContent, _jsonOptions);

            return new Token{
                AccessToken = results.Token
            };
        }
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MySendAsync(string method, string uri, string jsonContent, string headerToken = null)
    {
        try{
            using (HttpClientHandler httpHandler = new()){
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(method), uri){
                    Content = new NoEncodingJsonContent(jsonContent)
                };

                request.Headers.Add("API-KEY", _apiKey);

                if (headerToken != null){
                    request.Headers.Add("Token", headerToken);
                }

                httpHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

                using HttpClient client = new(httpHandler);
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

                return await client.SendAsync(request);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried various approaches that I was able to find on Google but none of them worked.

Comment: You need to use `IHttpClientFactory` and add it as a ctor parameter.

Comment: `using (HttpClientHandler httpHandler = new()){` <-- This won't scale. You'll run into problems. `HttpClientHandler` instances are meant to be pooled for about 2 minutes. If you only retain them for a single request then you'll encounter socket-exhaustion, but if you retain them for too long you'll have stale DNS records.

Comment: Do you use a mocking library? Which one?